# Why MySQL taking 150% CPU?

Tags: mysql

```
select * from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS;
(All other values was zero)

ABORTED_CLIENTS 97
ABORTED_CONNECTS    929
BINLOG_CACHE_DISK_USE   388
BINLOG_CACHE_USE    1533317
BINLOG_STMT_CACHE_USE   36
BYTES_RECEIVED  7615442185957
BYTES_SENT  21124731129872
COM_ADMIN_COMMANDS  218608
COM_ALTER_TABLE 271346
COM_BEGIN   124761197
COM_CHANGE_DB   812727
COM_COMMIT  124717516
COM_CREATE_DB   16
COM_CREATE_INDEX    140
COM_CREATE_TABLE    500481
COM_CREATE_USER 31
COM_DELETE  25794685
COM_DELETE_MULTI    106
COM_DROP_DB 5
COM_DROP_TABLE  134483
COM_DROP_USER   1
COM_EMPTY_QUERY 5
COM_FLUSH   687
COM_GRANT   84
COM_INSERT  157275633
COM_INSERT_SELECT   27107
COM_KILL    193
COM_LOAD    329
COM_LOCK_TABLES 8900
COM_OPTIMIZE    4
COM_RENAME_TABLE    24
COM_REPAIR  4
COM_REPLACE 2456
COM_REPLACE_SELECT  129284
COM_RESET   1
COM_ROLLBACK    64507
COM_SELECT  1499430250
COM_SET_OPTION  2106914723
COM_SHOW_CHARSETS   1
COM_SHOW_COLLATIONS 3
COM_SHOW_CREATE_TABLE   22934
COM_SHOW_DATABASES  207
COM_SHOW_ENGINE_STATUS  5
COM_SHOW_FIELDS 28862
COM_SHOW_GRANTS 77
COM_SHOW_KEYS   3278
COM_SHOW_MASTER_STATUS  34
COM_SHOW_PROCESSLIST    611
COM_SHOW_PROFILES   6
COM_SHOW_SLAVE_STATUS   9
COM_SHOW_STATUS 217620
COM_SHOW_STORAGE_ENGINES    2
COM_SHOW_TABLE_STATUS   18814
COM_SHOW_TABLES 33761
COM_SHOW_TRIGGERS   18836
COM_SHOW_VARIABLES  273
COM_SHOW_WARNINGS   34
COM_SLAVE_START 1
COM_SLAVE_STOP  2
COM_TRUNCATE    7764
COM_UNLOCK_TABLES   8884
COM_UPDATE  37469838
COM_UPDATE_MULTI    123259
COMPRESSION OFF
CONNECTIONS 1061520426
CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES 732030
CREATED_TMP_FILES   4652
CREATED_TMP_TABLES  54437170
FLUSH_COMMANDS  6
HANDLER_COMMIT  2182535689
HANDLER_DELETE  92518473
HANDLER_PREPARE 666739886
HANDLER_READ_FIRST  2474913926
HANDLER_READ_KEY    1059279433275
HANDLER_READ_LAST   43925
HANDLER_READ_NEXT   436768231787
HANDLER_READ_PREV   301447517
HANDLER_READ_RND    5952432968
HANDLER_READ_RND_NEXT   10348297916925
HANDLER_ROLLBACK    187102
HANDLER_UPDATE  2393576168
HANDLER_WRITE   86500295124
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_DATA   467845
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_DIRTY  889
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_FLUSHED    1424454404
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_MISC   56443
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_PAGES_TOTAL  524288
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_READ_AHEAD   29896084
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_READ_AHEAD_EVICTED   796227
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_READ_REQUESTS    4068149166333
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_READS    12520613
INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_WRITE_REQUESTS   20368367461
INNODB_DATA_FSYNCS  318779352
INNODB_DATA_READ    760018554880
INNODB_DATA_READS   17068014
INNODB_DATA_WRITES  840424175
INNODB_DATA_WRITTEN 24544126702080
INNODB_DBLWR_PAGES_WRITTEN  712227202
INNODB_DBLWR_WRITES 15776763
INNODB_HAVE_ATOMIC_BUILTINS ON
INNODB_LOG_WRITE_REQUESTS   2211878264
INNODB_LOG_WRITES   282197110
INNODB_OS_LOG_FSYNCS    287229151
INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN   1203187140608
INNODB_PAGE_SIZE    16384
INNODB_PAGES_CREATED    17749258
INNODB_PAGES_READ   46387717
INNODB_PAGES_WRITTEN    712227202
INNODB_ROW_LOCK_TIME    213614770
INNODB_ROW_LOCK_TIME_AVG    918
INNODB_ROW_LOCK_TIME_MAX    121381
INNODB_ROW_LOCK_WAITS   232551
INNODB_ROWS_DELETED 92530601
INNODB_ROWS_INSERTED    3207022434
INNODB_ROWS_READ    2960281468524
INNODB_ROWS_UPDATED 1363616617
KEY_BLOCKS_UNUSED   107171
KEY_BLOCKS_USED 107171
KEY_READ_REQUESTS   1917019435
KEY_WRITE_REQUESTS  506106457
MAX_USED_CONNECTIONS    425
OPEN_FILES  8
OPEN_TABLE_DEFINITIONS  322
OPEN_TABLES 1290
OPENED_FILES    5604054
OPENED_TABLE_DEFINITIONS    1546908
OPENED_TABLES   13175358
QCACHE_FREE_BLOCKS  118109
QCACHE_FREE_MEMORY  357148528
QCACHE_HITS 72966786
QCACHE_INSERTS  13890475
QCACHE_LOWMEM_PRUNES    6567150
QCACHE_NOT_CACHED   125386
QCACHE_QUERIES_IN_CACHE 302804
QCACHE_TOTAL_BLOCKS 724845
QUERIES 18424616323
QUESTIONS   18424616323
RPL_STATUS  AUTH_MASTER
SELECT_FULL_JOIN    2443436
SELECT_FULL_RANGE_JOIN  23689
SELECT_RANGE    9123386
SELECT_SCAN 7722106
SLAVE_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD  1800
SLOW_QUERIES    706238
SORT_MERGE_PASSES   53685
SORT_RANGE  7252979
SORT_ROWS   11381099801
SORT_SCAN   45876326
TABLE_LOCKS_IMMEDIATE   19423108
THREADS_CACHED  55
THREADS_CONNECTED   11
THREADS_CREATED 102479
THREADS_RUNNING 3
UPTIME  54103929
UPTIME_SINCE_FLUSH_STATUS   319362
```

**my.cnf**

```
skip_slave_start
replicate-do-db           = printvenue
innodb_lock_wait_timeout  = 120
user                      = mysql
port                      = 3306
socket                    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file                  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                   = /usr
datadir                   = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                    = /tmp
language                  = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
sql_mode                  = "ALLOW_INVALID_DATES"
max_allowed_packet        = 16M
thread_stack              = 192K
myisam-recover            = BACKUP
max_connections           = 2048
open_files_limit          = 16384
table_cache               = 4096
tmp_table_size            = 256M
sort_buffer_size          = 12M
read_buffer_size          = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size      = 8M
join_buffer_size          = 1M
key_buffer_size           = 128M
character_set_server      = utf8
collation_server          = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
innodb_buffer_pool_size   = 8192M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 24
thread_cache_size         = 64
thread_concurrency        = 32
query_cache_limit         = 2M
query_cache_size          = 768M
log_bin                   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log-bin-index             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index
sync_binlog               = 1
expire_logs_days          = 10
max_binlog_size           = 512M
log-slave-updates
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet        = 16M
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition
[isamchk]
key_buffer                = 16M
```

**vmstat 5 5**

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 1  0 381304 410284 195236 4431612    0    0     3    65    0    0  2  0 98  0
 0  0 381304 410276 195236 4432048    0    0    57  1674 3194 2983  7  0 92  0
 3  0 381304 410028 195236 4432176    0    0     3   222 3323 3060 13  1 86  0
 3  0 381304 409632 195244 4432392    0    0    31  1651 3558 3124 22  0 78  0
 0  0 381304 409384 195244 4432896    0    0    47   415 3445 2979 18  1 81  0
```

**dstat -tcdrgilmns 5**

```
----system---- ----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- --io/total- ---paging-- ----interrupts--- ---load-avg--- ------memory-usage----- -net/total->
     time     |usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| read  writ|  in   out |  94    95    96 | 1m   5m  15m | used  buff  cach  free| recv  send>
15-09 18:35:36|  2   0  98   0   0   0|  22k  517k|0.43  24.4 |  87B   88B|  35    35    36 |0.77 0.96 1.10|10.9G  191M 4331M  393M|   0     0 >
15-09 18:35:41| 14   0  85   0   0   0|   0  2446k|   0  80.8 |   0     0 | 203   297   195 |0.79 0.96 1.10|10.9G  191M 4331M  391M| 328k  723k>
15-09 18:35:46| 14   0  85   0   0   0|   0   246k|   0  42.2 |   0     0 | 239   175   361 |0.80 0.96 1.10|10.9G  191M 4331M  392M| 348k  798k>
15-09 18:35:51| 13   0  86   0   0   0|  38k 1609k|1.60  75.2 |   0     0 | 197   158   170 |0.98 1.00 1.11|10.9G  191M 4337M  386M| 203k  441k>
15-09 18:35:56| 14   1  85   0   0   0|  54k 1695k|2.40  47.6 |   0     0 | 388   243   183 |0.98 1.00 1.11|10.9G  191M 4340M  383M| 554k 1130k
```

Queries made per sec: ~600
Mix CRUD Operations
CPU CORES: 8
RAM: 16GB
Swap: Yes

Also, it gives very slow output sometimes. How to figure out the issue and solve.

Comment: What version of MySQL (`Please run SELECT VERSION();`)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA:  5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to unix like systems to use more than 100% of CPU when you have several physical cores. Therefore, in your case it can be up to 800%. And load-avg can be up to 8.

To get understanding why mysql gives such load please use The Slow Query Log: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

That will give you the list of most heavy queries.

Comment: Issue is not how come CPU is more than 100, its rather why a service like MySql is taking so much CPU?

Comment: MySQL easily can use a lot of CPU. One of the reason can be not optimal queries that do not use indexes while doing heavy for CPU operations such sorting, grouping.
You can find them using slow query log